# Swift: Cannot validate password

Tags: ios, validation, swift2

I'm trying to validate passwords in swift with this library `SwiftValidator` (https://github.com/jpotts18/SwiftValidator) but I'm being thrown this error:

> Argument labels '(delegate:)' do not match any available overloads

[image: SwiftValidator error]

How can I fix it? Also, is it possible for me to use an AlertView to display my message instead of a label? (at `errorLabel: errorMsg`)

This is my code:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import SwiftValidator
import Alamofire

class ResetPasswordViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

let validator = Validator()

@IBOutlet weak var errorMsg: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var usernameRP: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var passwordRP: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var confirmPasswordRP: UITextField!

@IBAction func submitBtnRP(sender: AnyObject) {
    validator.validate(delegate:self)
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    usernameRP.delegate = self

    passwordRP.delegate = self

    validator.registerField(usernameRP, rules: [RequiredRule(),  MinLengthRule(length: 4)])

    validator.registerField(passwordRP, rules: [RequiredRule(),  MinLengthRule(length: 6)])

    validator.registerField(confirmPasswordRP, errorLabel: errorMsg, rules: [ConfirmationRule(confirmField: passwordRP)])

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

func validationSuccessful() {
    // submit the form
}

func validationFailed(errors:[UITextField:ValidationError]) {
    // turn the fields to red
    for (field, error) in validator.errors {
        field.layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
        field.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        error.errorLabel?.text = error.errorMessage // works if you added labels
        error.errorLabel?.hidden = false
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply write below line on button click:

```
validator.validate(self)
```

and bind its validation delegate like this

```
class testViewController: UIViewController, ValidationDelegate
{

}
```

and yes you can also giving alert to user but its better that to shown every alert one by one if condition not met with criteria.

Comment: Is there a way (and how) for me to put my validator.registerField (inside ViewDidLoad) and validationSuccessful line of codes in a separate file? I'm trying to adopt the MVC approach

Comment: Your purpose is to doing some action when validationsuccessful is called?

Comment: yeah, if possible, I would like to port all data handling stuff to another file

Comment: if you want to perform some action like data handling or API calling, then simply call postnotification or prepared your own delegate and fired your delegate methods from in that validationSuccesful function.